# Playwright, how to deactivate page or put it to background?

Tags: playwright

In our tests we need to check how a page behaves when tab is inactive, is in background mode.

Our scenario looks like this:

1. Open our video app
2. Play a video from the app
3. Open new page and go to any page, e.g. Bing (to have our app page in background mode)
4. Stay on the new page for 10 seconds
5. Go back to previous page with video app
6. Check if video is paused (this is expected functionality)

As I read, creating a new page in Playwright doesn't mean old one goes to background automatically. Because of that the test above fails as our app page is active and video is still playing. Is there any way to put it to background?

I tried putting this Bing page to front using `.bringToFront()` method, but without any success.
Tried creating new context, but still, after closing it video in a previous context was playing.

Comment: That's not possible at the moment. See https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3570

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.